# How to log changed(CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE) table fields in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
       id                   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       name                 TEXT NOT NULL,
       barcode          INTEGER NOT NULL,
       category_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
       unit_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
       count            INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       purchase_price   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       extra_charge         INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       selling_price    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       created_at           DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
       update_at            DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
       user_id          INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

"INSERT INTO  'products' (name, barcode, category_id, unit_id, count, purchase_price,
extra_charge, selling_price, user_id)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

CREATE TABLE product_changes_log  (

)

Comment: What's the question? You posted just a `CREATE TABLE` statement. Have you tried using [triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) which will create `products_history` table and log all changes from all DML statements.

For SQLite you can use [AFTER INSERT Triggers](https://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html)

There is also `AFTER UPDATE` and `DELETE` if you need to log those changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log AFTER INSERT ON products
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product_changes_log  (column1,column2)

          values (new.column1,new.column2);

END;
```

Comment: for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE will be one DB ?

Comment: <pre> <code>  this like: 
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log AFTER INSERT ON products
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product_changes_log  (column1,column2)
            values (new.column1,new.column2);

END;

for UPDATE: 
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log AFTER UPDATE ON products
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product_changes_log  (column1,column2)
            values (new.column1,new.column2);

END;
FOR  DELETE:
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log AFTER DELETE ON products
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product_changes_log  (column1,column2)
            values (new.column1,new.column2);

END; 
</code>

Comment: Yes please open the link provided and scroll down to [Logging All Inserts, Updates, and Deletes](https://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html)  , you need to put `;` between them